# Not able to install app in Android emulator - Titanium

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium, titanium-mobile, genymotion

I was trying to install the application on Android Emulator. I did not install the Genymotion Emulators. But I got these errors. I am not able to identify the reason behind it. Can anyone help me to understand and remove this?

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.4.2, Titanium SDK version 3.5.1.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2015, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 8
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/longjohn/dist/longjohn.js:185
        throw e;
              ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/opt/local/scgi_temp'
    at fs.readdirSync (fs.js:666:18)
    at scan (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/emulators/genymotion.js:136:25)
    at scan (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/emulators/genymotion.js:148:26)
    at scan (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/emulators/genymotion.js:148:26)
    at /Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/emulators/genymotion.js:154:10
    at /Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/emulators/genymotion.js:111:8
    at q.process (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:731:21)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:354:15)
---------------------------------------------
    at async.setImmediate (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:96:15)
    at /Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:696:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
    at _insert (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:681:11)
    at q.push (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:708:15)
    at /Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/emulators/genymotion.js:127:12
    at queue.drain (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:108:3)
---------------------------------------------
    at Object.run (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:59:8)
    at find (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:96:14)
    at q.process (/Users/sp/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.1.GA/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:809:21)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:354:15)
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its look like permission error. you can try

```
chmod 777 -R /opt/local/scgi_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install using the the `adb install` command

Example - `adb install <path to apk file>`